# Can I load bitmap data from the library in AS3 without specifying a class name for linkage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a movie clip that holds one bitmap image, some simple AS3 to change the image displayed, and a ton of bitmaps I've imported into my library.

Currently, I swap the images by changing the bitmapData

`holder.bitmapData = new test2(1,1);`

but this requires me to check off 'Export for ActionScript' in every symbol.  I'd rather not go through every bitmap in the library and do this, is there some way to reference them by their library name?

Thanks,
-S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Export for ActionScript' is needed. But you don't have to do it by hand. Just write a simple JSFL script for flash